# Multiple Google Analytics Events not tracked as conversions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, real-time, google-ads-api, goal-tracking

I have just created a Free Trial sign up form that consists of four stages. Each stage requires different information from a user and the form is navigated by clicking on 'continue' buttons once the required fields for a given stage is completed.

What I am trying to do is add a unique **Google Event** for **each** of the 'continue' buttons.

I have tried this (all stages are within the same HTML):

**Stage 1 Continue button** = ga ('send', 'event', 'freeTrialPage', 'Stage1');

**Stage 2 Continue button** = ga ('send', 'event', 'freeTrialPage', 'Stage2');

**Stage 3 Continue button** = ga ('send', 'event', 'freeTrialPage', 'Stage3');

**Stage 4 Create Account button** = ga ('send', 'event', 'freeTrialPage', 'register');

The events are all firing as expected (have used the debugger) and I can see results of successful hits by going to *Real Time > Conversion > Goal Hits (Last 30 min)* in Google Analytics.

**The issue is** that **only some** (1-2) of the 'continue' button hits appear under *Conversions > Goals > Overview* (The Create Account button event on the other hand shows up as expected in both Real Time and Conversions Overview) in Google Analytics.

I am using the same **google_conversion_id**, **google_conversion_label** and **Google Adwords Conversion img** `<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1234567890/?label=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>` (not the actual code)
for all of the events, this could potentially be the issue, but I'm pretty sure it isn't.

This is how I've been defining my goals: Google Goal setup:
[image: Google Goal setup]

I should also mention that I **HAVE** been getting data for Stage1, Stage2, and Stage3 events in *Conversions > Goals > Overview* but the numbers are so far removed from what I see under *Real Time > Conversion > Goal Hits*.

Comment: Adwords conversion tracking is not really related to Google Analytics tracking, so that's not the issue. Also you mention goals, but not how you defined your goals. It may take some time before data shows up in the standard report, so did you wait a couple o hours ?

Comment: @Eike Ok. I've just added an image at the bottom of the question with a screenshot of Stage 1's Goal setup/definition, each goal/event is the same apart from the action. Yeah, I thought this may have been the case but I have been testing and debugging this for a few days now (even left it over the weekend) and the data i'm getting doesn't match up. The Create Account button event on the other hand works as expected, and I get results in _Conversions > Goals > Overview_ almost instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**More of a work around solution than an answer**

Turns out I was looking at the wrong view in Google Analytics.

*Conversions > Goals > Overview* shows limited data for each event, so it wasn't registering every occurrence of the events firing.

*Behaviour > Events > Overview* then filtering to a particular action (of an event) shows all the occurrences of that event firing. Perfect for what I need to see.